# How to resolve this deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, java-threads

I have added comments in code to explain from where deadlock is occurring.
Basically, There are two threads. Each thread acquires lock on an `Manager` object and then go for acquiring lock on static resource, which is a map of all the `Manager` objects in the application.Both thread calls `get()` on map.
`Manager` class has overridden `equals()` method. `equals()` further calls some synchronized method of `Manager` class. So a `get()` on map will need object level lock on each object in the map one by one until key matches because equals is overridden.
I can only change the code in sub classes(`Sub1` and `Sub2`) and avoid the deadlock, as I don't have access to other classes.

Edit: I don't have access to syncMap. The code in 'synchronized' block executes in third party code whose API I call to.

Can I avoid this by acquiring lock in `finally` on `Manager`, rather than before try block ?!

```
    public class Parent{
        protected Manager manager;
    }

    public class Global{
        private static final Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
        //syncMap contains all the objects of Manager in the application
    }

    class Manager{


        public boolean equals(Object o){

            Manager obj = (Manager)o;
            return obj.getURL().equals(getURL());
        }

        public final synchronized String getURL(){
            return msettings.getDBURL(); //msettings is a global variable
        }


    }


    //Thread-1 is executing someMethod() of this class

    class Sub1 extends Parent{
        Global global;
        //consider manager and Global object are not null
        public void someMethod()
        {
            synchronized(manager){// Thread-1 succesfully takes object level lock on a manager object, say Manager01
                try{
                    global.syncMap.get(manager);
                    // Thread-1 Succesfully takes class level lock on syncMap
                    //  get() calls equals() for each object in syncMap. 
                    //equals() need object lock on each Manager Object in map as it further calls synchronized getURL()
                    // But on one manager Object(Manager02) Thread-2 has already acquired lock and is waiting for lock on syncMap which this thread-1 holds

                }
                finally{
                    manager.releaseConnection();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //Thread-2 is executing otherMethod() of this class
    class Sub2 extends Parent{ 
        public void otherMethod()
        {
            synchronized(manager){// this takes a lock on manager(Manager02)
                try{
                    global.syncMap.get(manager);
                    // this is blocked as syncMap is aquired by thread-1


                }
                finally{
                    manager.releaseConnection();
                }

            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: why do you think there would be a deadlock? this code applies ordered intrinsic lock with synchronized(manager), so I don't see deadlock...

Comment: I am facing the deadlock at my employer organization. And thread dump says this is happening here only. Thread-1 is having class level lock on syncMap, and is waiting for lock on an instance of  Manager class available in SyncMap. Another thread is having lock on Manager object already and is waiting for lock on SyncMap. Manager can have many instances and all the instances are in SyncMap for record.

Comment: There's no point, at all, to force a design, where `equals` is doing synchronised stuff, get rid of it. At best evaluating `equals` in some client code will tell you, what the state was *during the call of equals* and gives no promises of the state after the call. Instead implement atomic operations (`trySomeOperation`) that tell the caller if the conditions required were as expected and the operation was performed.

Comment: how Sub1 and Sub2 objects instantiated? Are they hold very same manager instance? can you describe how do you launch your threads?

Comment: Sub1 and sub2 have different manager objects. Manager objects are returned by some API call, whichwe don't have access to. The API keeps track of all the manager objects via Map. For simplicity, I have not shown API calls. I looked into API code via java decompiler and have added that code in syncronized block of my code to make it simple to post here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should try to eliminate the need for synchronization in the  `equals` method. It will cause more trouble than it solves so if a redesign is possible then I think thats the best way.

However, if you restructure the code a bit and move the `global.syncMap.get(manager)` to before the `synchronization` block it would not generate a deadlock

```
public Class Parent{
    protected Manager manager;
}

class Global{
    private static final Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
    //syncMap contains all the objects of Manager in the application
}

class Manager{


    public boolean equals(Object o){

        Manager obj = (Manager)o;
        return obj.getURL().equals(getURL());
    }

    public final synchronized String getURL(){
        return msettings.getDBURL(); //msettings is a global variable
    }


}


//Thread-1 is executing someMethod() of this class

class Sub1 extends Parent{
    Global global;
    //consider manager and Global object are not null
    public void someMethod()
    {
         try {
             global.syncMap.get(manager);
             synchronized(manager){

             }
         }
         finally{
             manager.releaseConnection();
         }            
    }
}

//Thread-2 is executing otherMethod() of this class
class Sub2 extends Parent{ 
    public void otherMethod()
    {
         try {
             global.syncMap.get(manager);
             synchronized(manager){

             }
         }
         finally{
             manager.releaseConnection();
         }                        
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE** Alternative synchronization over `Global.class`, could probably use instance variable `global` also instead of `Global.class`

**UPDATE** Changed synchronization to be over `Manager.class` instead of `Global.class`.

```
class Sub1 extends Parent
{
    Global global;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        synchronized (Manager.class) { 
            try {
                global.syncMap.get(manager);
            }
            finally {
                manager.releaseConnection();
            }
        }
    }
}


class Sub2 extends Parent
{
    Global global;

    public void otherMethod()
    {
        synchronized (Manager.class) { 
            try {
                global.syncMap.get(manager);
            }
            finally {
                manager.releaseConnection();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doing so you letting two thread to work on same manager data, so there can be new concurrency issues: as I can see original idea was to put  manager.releaseConnection() method call inside synchronized block...

Comment: Thanks. I cannot change the design. I have access to Sub classes only. And actual synchronized block is like below, which makes an API call. Inside that API all bad thing happens. I extracted the code from API and put in synchronized block while asking question for simplicity. synchronized (manager) {
            try {
                fdb1Objssert = routedDrug.getFDBClassifications();
            } finally {
                manager.returnConnection();
            }

Answer (score 1):

After new portion of information I don't see another solution except of turning all processing into serial-style. So you can put all manager-associated API calls in one synchronized method of some wrapping class and use this wrapper as a single entry-point for third-party API.

```
class BrutalWrapper {
    public synchronized void doIt(Manager manager)
    {
        try{
            global.syncMap.get(manager);

        }
        finally{
            manager.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}

class Sub1 extends Parent{
    BrutalWrapper brutal;
    public void someMethod()
    {
        brutal.doIt(manager);
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Parent{
    BrutalWrapper brutal;
    public void someMethod()
    {
        brutal.doIt(manager);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to syncMap. The code I have placed in sync block executes in an API call i don't have access to. I have access to only Manager Object

Comment: you said that you can change Sub1 and Sub2 class, and you showed Global object as part of Sub1 class, and global.syncMap.get method call in Sub1... you should be more specific in your question then

Comment: then what class/method really can access syncMap object?

Comment: @nukie: You either need to make sure `Sub1` and `Sub2` use the same instance of  `BrutalMapper`, or make the `doIt` method static. Otherwise this will not work...

Comment: @gustf actually I have mentioned that: _... and use this wrapper as a single entry-point for third-party API_

Comment: Ok, good that you already thought about that. Maybe would be an idea to make that more clear... maybe something like: *and use **one** instance of this wrapper...*